# How to apply Nested Select using Linq

Tags: linq, lambda

I'm working with nested select and seems like what i am doing is not correct!.

I'm trying to retrieve all the `Topics` items.

```
public class Employee
{
   public int Id{ get; set; }  
   //....other fields....
   //......
   public IList<Topics> Interest { get; set; }     
}

public class Topics
{
   public int Id { get; set; }  ;
   public string Name { get; set; }  ;
   //other fields
}

employeeItems = (from _emp in employees
                   select new Employee
                   {
                      EmpId = _emp.mediaId,
                      EmpName = _emp.mediaType,
                      ......................
                      Interest = (from _emp1 in employees.Interest  //has few rows
                      select new Topic 
                      {
                          Id = _emp1.Topics[0].Id,   //.<int>("id"), <<<ERROR
                          Name = _emp1.Topics[0].Name //["name"] <<<ERROR
                      }).ToList()

               }).ToList();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Interest = (from topic in _emp.Interest.SelectMany(i=>i.Topic)  //has few rows
                      select new Topic 
                      {
                          Id = topic.Id,   //.<int>("id"), <<<ERROR
                          Name = topic.Name //["name"] <<<ERROR
                      })

public class Employee
{
   public int Id{ get; set; }  
   //....other fields....
   //......
   public IEnumerable<Topics> Interest { get; set; }     
}
```

Leave the property as `IEnumerable` and don't do `.ToList()` inside the query. And it seems to me your data structure is employee has multiple interests and each interest has multiple topics, that's why I used `SelectMany`, but you can adjust it if I'm wrong with the data.